# Error while inflating linear linearlayout

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm inflating `linearlayout` to display facebook's banner ad. It is showing following error:
[image: error]

I added the same codes, same dependency to show fb's banner ad in another project and it is working there but it is showing this error in this project. I also replaced the linear layout with `relativelayout` and it is showing same error.

These are my codes:

```java
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
        adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_banner), AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
        RelativeLayout adContainer =  findViewById(R.id.fbAdsView);
        adContainer.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd();
        RateItDialogFragment.show(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        initVar();
        initView();
        loadData();
        initListener();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //unregister broadcast receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(newNotificationReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //register broadcast receiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(AppConstant.NEW_NOTI);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(newNotificationReceiver, intentFilter);

        initNotification();
    }

    // received new broadcast
    private BroadcastReceiver newNotificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            initNotification();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AppUtilities.tapPromptToExit(mActivity);
    }

    private void initVar() {
        mActivity = MainActivity.this;
        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        mContentList = new ArrayList<>();
        mFavoriteList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void initView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mNotificationView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.notificationView);
        mImgBtnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSearch);

        mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContent);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        mAdapter = new ContentAdapter(mContext, mActivity, mContentList);
        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        initToolbar(false);
        initDrawer();
        initLoader();
    }

    private void initListener() {
        //notification view click listener
        mNotificationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewActivity(mActivity, NotificationListActivity.class, false);
            }
        });

        // Search button click listener
        mImgBtnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeNewActivity(mActivity, SearchActivity.class, false);
            }
        });
                            mFavoriteDbController.insertData(model.getTitle(), model.getSubTitle(), model.getDetails(), model.getImageUrl());
                            mContentList.get(position).setFavorite(true);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.added_to_fav), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.card_view_top:
                        ActivityUtilities.getInstance().invokeDetailsActiviy(mActivity, DetailsActivity.class, model, false);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void loadData() {
        showLoader();

        // Initialize Favorite Database
        mFavoriteDbController = new FavoriteDbController(mContext);
        mFavoriteList.addAll(mFavoriteDbController.getAllData());

        loadJson();
   }

    private void loadJson() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(AppConstant.CONTENT_FILE)));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        parseJson(sb.toString());
    }

    private void parseJson(String jsonData) {
        try {

            JSONObject jsonObjMain = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObjMain.getJSONArray(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_ITEMS);

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_TITLE);
                String subTitle = jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_SUB_TITLE);
                String imageUrl = jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_IMAGE_URL);
                String details = jsonObj.getString(AppConstant.JSON_KEY_DETAILS);

                // Check for favorite
                boolean isFavorite = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < mFavoriteList.size(); j++) {
                    if (mFavoriteList.get(j).getTitle().equals(title)) {
                        isFavorite = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                mContentList.add(new Contents(title, subTitle, imageUrl, details, isFavorite));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        hideLoader();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void initNotification() {
        NotificationDbController notificationDbController = new NotificationDbController(mContext);
        TextView notificationCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notificationCount);
        notificationCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ArrayList<NotificationModel> notiArrayList = notificationDbController.getUnreadData();

        if (notiArrayList != null && !notiArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            int totalUnread = notiArrayList.size();
            if (totalUnread > 0) {
                notificationCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notificationCount.setText(String.valueOf(totalUnread));
            } else {
                notificationCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fbAdsView"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_3dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rvContent" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fbAdsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am so confused why am I getting this error.

Comment: Need to `setContentView` (done in `initView`) prior to any `findViewById`.

Comment: @Andy like he mentioned. Move the initView() to set below `super.OnCreate`. Then you can able to find the views inside the relative layout.

Comment: @madan did you try what we mentioned ?

Comment: @cantona_7 yes, this question is solved, i want help in that webview one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the views inside, you have to define the initView(), right below the oncreate as follows, then you can find the views inside the layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initView();
    // follows with rest of your code
}
```